# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Just upgraded TFS and Build server to 2015 and now getting the following error when running a CodedUI test.  Any suggestions?

```
Error adding test case [3251] to test run: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **install VS2015** **on the build agent machine** to get the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll. After VS2015 is installed, you can get it in the path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

TFS runs builds on the TFS build agent machine, so for best practice you need to have the same dev related software environment on the build server.

Comment: Vicky, I checked the build server and build agent and VS2015 is installed.  I went to the path you specified and the .dll is there.  It is version 14.0.23107.0

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  I can verify the files mentioned are in the location specified.  No dice though.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and the files were already in place on the build server.  I GACed the assemblies in question on the build server, next release worked fine.

Perhaps related was the assembly in question was on the E: drive from my local system, so it was saved with that path in the csproj file, anyway GACing the files took care of the error.